# Java Query for retrieving records not in the foreign key table

Tags: java, database

Hi i want to have a query to retrieve records which is not in the another table. For eg.(*List all the room Number which is unoccupied at singapore hotel*).

```
Room               Hotel            Booking
--------      --------------   ------------------
room_no          hotel_no           hotel_no
hotel_no         hotel_name         room_no
                                    date_from
                                    date_to
```

is there any way to retrieve this record with just one sql query?

Comment: Is this SQL? What database do you use? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you tell if a room is occupied?

Comment: in my opinion, i would think that if the room_no is not in the booking table then it's unoccupied. i should retrieve the room_no that are not in the booking table

Comment: This will only give you the rooms that *never* are occupied. Are you not interested in the occupation date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query

```
 select room_no
   from room
  where room_no not in 
        (select room_no 
           from Booking 
          where hotel_no = singapore_hotel_no)
```

Comment: Its not handling the booking dates date_from and date_to

Answer (score 0):

```
Select room.roon_num
from Room left outer join Hotel on room.room_no = hotel.room_no
left outer join Booking on room.room_no = booking.room_no and hotel.hotel_no = booking.hotel_no
where hotel.hotel_name = ? 
and not (? between (booking.date_from , booking.date_to))
```

here first `?` is `'singapore hotel'`
and second `?` is date for which you want to query